# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' after Shopify store owner confirms recurring charge in embedded app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have a Shopify embedded app (loaded in an iframe in Shopify dashboard).

After the store owner confirms a recurring charge, my app makes a POST request, then the store owner is redirected to the embedded app home page. But Shopify detects that the app is not being loaded in an iframe, so it redirects the store owner the the embedded url.

Then I get the error

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' The target origin
>   provided does not match the recipient window's origin .

I'm assuming this is happening because we're posting prior to the redirect from the non-embedded host. But then my post goes through on the second request.

Is it fine to leave this as is, or is there any way to avoid the first post error?